# structure and use in app socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I want to have a structure for my application, but do not know how to call socket.io from sub-router and attach it to the server express

//app.js

```
var express = require('express')
 , http = require('http')
 , path = require('path'):
 , i18n = require("i18n");

var app = express();
.
.
app.use(app.router);
require('./routes')(app);
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
   console.log("Express port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

//routes.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {
 var rou_admin = require('./routers/admin')
 ,   rou_login = require('./routers/login')
 ,   rou_page  = require('./routers/page')
 ,   rou_logou = require('./routers/logout');

function restrict(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.user){
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
}

//General
app.get('/', rou_page.page); 

//Admin
app.get('/admin', rou_admin.admin);
//xxxx
app.get('/xxxx', rou_admin.xxxx);
//ssss
app.get('/ssss', rou_admin.ssss);
.
.
};
```

//routes/admin.js

```
 exports.admin = function(req, res){
  res.render('index',{title: 'Chat Room'})
  var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

  io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
          ...code...
  }
};
```

How could I do this, If you have a lot better idea.
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

Answer (score 1):

You already got most of the solution. Just make few changes :

routes.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {
var rou_admin = require('./routers/admin')(app),  //pass app to routes/admin.js itself
```

routes/admin.js

```
function admin(app)
{

  admin.start= function(req, res){
  res.render('index',{title: 'Chat Room'})
  var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

          ...code...
  };
}
module.exports = admin;
```

here it just defines the function, you can use admin.start() to execute your code.